# how to grab product lists from cj, clickbank and linkshare, ebay using api?

Tags: api, curl, cj, clickbank, linkshare

Hello i want to get the product lists from cj, clickbank and linkshare via API's to display the whole lists on my site , if this is possible or its a nightmare , where am i standing please generous reply is needed, tell me how to grab the product list using their respective API's , i have found alot of blogs and posts regarding this but none is enough to solve my prob, thats y i said a nightmare.

this is what i got for clickbank

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/products/list");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/xml",  "Authorization:DEV-7979307A05A8A50B6535A5AD5DCD8EDB060B:API-4D297E18498B51B70EA986DC7422B1BCE488"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

the apikey and dev key is the real one of my affiliate account i created , i am giving the real info because i need it to be done, it is throwing the same error , site parameter is missing,

same is what i want for the other two.

much thanks in advance . cheers.

Comment: Are you 100% committed to solving this problem yourself? There's a TON of complexity here and you might find it easier to use existing solutions already out there on the market. [PopShops](http://www.popshops.com/) will aggregate all of those product offers for you from the different networks and let you consume that data any way you like.

Comment: thankx jonaz for suggesting me the solution :) , and yeah the task is to grab the product list from these sites, well ClickBank is giving its xml feed for whole product list, https://support.clickbank.com/entries/22824126-marketplace-feed here, i had parsed this xml, and soon i will write code for it to grab that from the direct link not to download, so that when they will update i will get updated products. same can be the solution for the CJ and link share,maybe, i am again searching :p lolxx so if any one can still suggest me on what i had asked before and what i am doing, wl b grateful:)

Answer (score 0):

Okey , that question i posted was somewhat one and half month before , i know answers are present all around the web but scattered and i want them to be gathered so if some one need it can use it.

first of all i am giving you for CJ, Comission Junction:
1) Creat a page e.g  cjcall.php and put the following code on that page.

```
// CJ Product Grabing cjcall.php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://product-search.api.cj.com/v2/product-search?website-id=YOUR-SITE-ID&keywords=KEYWORD&records-per-page=30&serviceable-area=US");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,false); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/xml",  "Authorization:YOUR-CJ-DEVELOPER-ID"));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

THIS will give you responce of products against your keyword if it is matching products.

you can get you result the way you want i figured it this way that i created a new page called cjcronjob.php and put the following code on that page and run it , there you can use the product details, i.e may be save in the database.

//cjcronjob.php

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('ABSOLUTE-PATH-TO-THE-FIRST-CJCALL.PHP-FILE/cjcall.php');


$object = simplexml_load_string($homepage);


    foreach($object->products->product as $cjres)
    {

}
```

nOW each product is in your control use it in here inside the foreach loop which will run twenty times here as specified in the curl call.
clickbank is still a mystery , may be they dont allow you to perform more against their API

Comment: dude accept your own answer (if the code works. It will be helpful for the readers to find working solution then)

Answer (score 0):

okey the second was linkshare product grabing from linkshare , which is a bit different than other affiliate channels, in a sence that here first you will create relation on the linkshare advertisers , and you can the products of those who will allow you to be his advertiser or affiliate:

here is the code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

    $cv = curl_version();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://productsearch.linksynergy.com/productsearch?token=YOUR-LINKSHARE-TOKEN-ID-A-VERY-LONG-STRING&keyword=%22YOUR-KEYWORD%22&MaxResults=20&pagenumber=1&mid=MID-THE-ID-OF-THE-ADVERTIZER-WHO-HAS-ALLOWED-YOU&sort=retailprice&sorttype=asc&sort=productname&sorttype=asc");
$xml_data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$object = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);

    foreach($object->item as $signprod)
    {}
```

under the foreach loop you can do what ever you want, just print_r($signprod) and you will get the details , put the keyword matching against your allowed advertiser's product, by helping you more say i have a relation with some cookies site, who's MID is xxxxx , then i write cookies in the keyword and it get results for me, do accordingly.
its simple and yeah it will take a long time on net if someone is new like me, which i was before more than a month ago.